# Document Alternative? DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

So I was advised recently not to use document.write. But I can't seem to figure out how to use DOM manipulation to make it document print on screen. This function works so that you hit the button enter the number of miles traveled by car and you get your carbon foot print. Only with document.write it overwrites the entire page after you click the button. I tried getElementbyId but it doesn't seem to print anything so I know I'm probably not using it correctly. Any ideas on an alternative that will complete the function without overwriting the page would be much helpful>

Below is the code I have with just document.write, the one that overwrites the entire page:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button").click(function() {

            var myNumber = 19.2;
            var myAnswer = prompt ("How many miles did you travel?");
            document.write( " Your Carbon Foot print is:" + myAnswer * myNumber + "lbs" );

          });
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery you don't have to worry about the low-level DOM manipulation methods. You can just use `$("#id").text("foo");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM manipulation involves creating document elements and inserting them into the document tree.  It's something that should become second nature to you if you want to do extensive work with JS:

```
- document.write(...
+ $("<span>").text(' Your Carbon Foot print ...').appendTo("body");
```

You probably want to append the text to something else, but the above should have a similar affect and not overwrite the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're fairly new to JQuery - welcome!

Once you have JQuery, you very rarely (if ever) need to go back to document.write or other low-level DOM tools (although it's still essential to know them from time to time)

So, starting with the HTML. You'd probably go with something like :

```
<button id="calcbutton">Calculate Footprint</button>
<div id="carbonresult"></div>
```

I've used an id to identify the button rather than the class in your example (remember id's should be unique, classes can apply to multiple elements) but your way would still work.

For the script then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#calcbutton").click(function(){
        var convFactor = 19.2;
        var milesTravelled = prompt("How many miles did you travel?");
        var resultMsg = " Your Carbon Footprint is: " + milesTravelled * convFactor
        $("#carbonresult").text(resultMsg);
    });
});
```

By using JQuery to place the result inside the element of your choice using .text(), .html() or append() you have far more control.